how to set dart sdk on android studio from the full flutter sdk

This is what it's showing me
What can I do about this?  from android studio
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/user/Desktop/flutter_projects/mi_card_flutter/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/user/.gradle/caches/7.0.2/scripts/1445wdyck9xmnqxfk9atcnkpf).


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 65


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


The issue you are seeing,

'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class
file major version 65

means that you are using an incompatible Java version for your project conflicting with what is set inside your project.
You can check your defined Java version under Android Studio -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

In comparison, check what settings you placed in your application level build.gradle:
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
        targetCompatibility = "1.8"
    }

and also check your current Gradle version.
